# No module named win32com

Tags: python

I've just installed Python for the first time and I'm trying to reference the win32com module however, whenever I try to import it I get the message "no module name win32com".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As it is not built into Python, you will need to install it.

`pip install pywin`

Comment: I've managed to install pywin just now however, import win32com (or pywin) returns the same error message.

Comment: @CBusBus Can you check the output of print(sys.path) and pip install pywin? Maybe the package is installed into a wrong place.

Answer (score 12):

the below plus add pywin32 in PyCharm setting work for me

```
python -m pip install pywin32
```

Answer (score 5):

Since win32com is a Windows-specific package, this answer will be geared towards Windows users.

## Option 1: Install locally with pipenv (recommended)

You can use a package manager like pipenv to manage your dependencies.

1. Ensure you have pipenv installed (`pip install pipenv`).
2. In your project directory, run `pipenv install pypiwin32` to install the package.
3. Now you can run your code using commands like the following `pipenv run main.py`

Example `main.py` code:

```py
import win32com

print(win32com)
```

## Option 2: Install locally with venv (recommended)

If pipenv isn't your thing, you can use the built-in virtual environments.

1. From your project directory, run `python -m venv venv` to setup you virtual environment.
2. Run `venv\Scripts\activate.bat` from your project directory whenever you want to use this virtual environment (you will see `(venv)` added to your shell prompt to know it's activated).
3. Run `pip install pypiwin32` from your active virtual environment to install the package.
4. You can run your code like `python main.py` so long as the virtual environment is active.

## Option 3: Install globally (typically not recommended)

This is not typically recommended, but included anyway.

1. Using `pip install pypiwin32` you can install the package globally.
2. Then you can run your code with just `python main.py`.

Answer (score 1):

When working with python projects its always a good idea to create a so called virtual environment, this way your modules will be more organized and reduces the import errors.

for example lets assume that you have a script.py which imports multiple modules including pypiwin32.

#### here are the steps to solve your problem:

1. depending on you operating system you need to download and install virtualenv package, in debian its as simple as `sudo apt install virtualenv` .

2. after installing 'virtualenv' package go to your project/script folder and create a virtualenv folder with `virtualenv venv` it creates a folder named `venv` in that directory.

3. activate your virtualenv `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate` if your already in the directory where venv exists just issue `source venv/bin/activate`

4. after activating your venv install you project dependencies `pip install pypiwin32` or `pip install pywin`

5. run your script, it wont throw that error again :)

Answer (score 1):

This will work as well

`python -m pip install pywin32`

Answer (score 0):

You should try using `pip` this way:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

It is `pypiwin32` which should work.