# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'win32com'

Tags: python-3.x, windows, windows-10, mobaxterm

Actually, I have the same problem as him:

[No module named win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535422/no-module-named-win32com)

I have installed pywin32 but MobaXterm tells me "No module named win32com".[image]

However, I am able to run my program using IDLE with no error.

[image]

What's the problem?

Code:

```
import win32com.client
import sys, os
shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut('C:/Users/Seaky/Desktop/CS 160.lnk')
os.chdir(shortcut.Targetpath)
```

What I am doing is that I am trying to do "cdlnk path" in the terminal using python code, where the path is a shortcut folder like the path above instead of a real path.

I used different code for running in the terminal and the IDLE but I only changed the path string from `sys.argv[1]` to the current one, which should not affect the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named win32com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35535422/no-module-named-win32com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out. The compiler of python installed in the MobaXterm doesn't have the pywin32 module.